# Calling link in angular not working in chrome but works in ie

Tags: html, angularjs, google-chrome

We are using xarios phone manager and in my angular app i use

```
 var url="dialfrompm://phonenumberhere";
        window.open(url,'_newtab');
```

This works in IE but in chrome it just doesn't do anything, does anyone have any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

This one works to my project
      window.open(url,'_blank')

Answer (score 0):

It might not work well when using Angular UI Router or ngRouter.

You can try to use $window.location.href. 
You must first inject $window in your controller.